# a WordPress connected to 2 database

Tags: posts, wp-query

Is it possible that Wordpress works from two databases?

I would like the post published by web A to be reflected on web B

Web A would only affect the information in the tables

```
wp_postmeta
wp_posts
```

What I've researched is using the $wpdb
Is there any way to do it? I don't know where to start

I would take your help

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by that precisely?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you rather try to  connect 2 wordpress to the same database ? 
On website B you can heavily restrain the capabilities of users. This way it will be only a sort of mirror.

Another path could be to use the rest API from website A to fuel the content from website B. Have a look on api documentation: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/

Comment: I can not put the 2 web in the same database because web B would send me to WEB A, that is a redirection

Comment: Yes you're right, so REST API definitely seems the good solution for that.